# Multiprocess multiple files in a list

Tags: python, multithreading, list, csv, multiprocess

I am trying to read a list that contains N number of .csv files stored in a list synchronously.

Right now I do the following:

import multiprocess

1. Empty list
2. Append list with listdir of .csv's
3. def A() -- even files (list[::2])
4. def B() -- odd files (list[1::2]
5. Process 1 def A()
6. Process 2 def B()

   ```
   def read_all_lead_files(folder):

       for files in glob.glob(folder+"*.csv"):
           file_list.append(files)
           def read_even():
              file_list[::2]    
           def read_odd():
              file_list[1::2]  

        p1 = Process(target=read_even)
        p1.start()
        p2 = Process(target=read_odd)
        p2.start()
   ```

Is there a faster way to split up the partitioning of the list to Process function?

Comment: You're saying you do different processing on "even" and "odd" files (whatever *that* means)?

Comment: "Faster"? In what sense? Are the two functions actually different in some way? Without at least a little knowledge of what the two functions do and what you're trying to improve, I don't see how we can help you. Post some minimal code.

Comment: The actual splitting of the list into even and odd is very fast. But A() / B() on every other file seems very arbitrary. Why are you doing that?

Comment: POSTing to a server. Governance only allows certain amount of connections per POST. Multiple POSTS gets around this issue.

Comment: I asked because I guessed that you wanted a Pool and didn't really need even/odd A/B. Looks like I was correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm guessing here at your request, because the original question is quite unclear. Since `os.listdir` doesn't guarantee an ordering, I'm assuming your "two" functions are actually identical and you just need to perform the same process on multiple files simultaneously.

The easiest way to do this, in my experience, is to spin up a `Pool`, launch a process for each file, and then wait. e.g.

```
import multiprocessing

def process(file):
    pass # do stuff to a file

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
for f in glob.glob(folder+"*.csv"):
    # launch a process for each file (ish).
    # The result will be approximately one process per CPU core available.
    p.apply_async(process, [f]) 

p.close()
p.join() # Wait for all child processes to close.
```

Comment: glob returns a list. you could replace the for loop with `p.apply_async(process, glob(folder+"*.csv"))`

Comment: @tdelaney I think you mean `p.map_async`, in which case yes, that's true. I chose to spell it out with an explicit loop because it's easier to see what's going on this way.

Comment: @HenryKeiter - you're right! got may maps and applies backwards.

Comment: thanks, this was very useful for my photo conversion utility.